# How to click this button?

Tags: vba, button, click, src

Hi all I am a beginner in Visual Basic. Your help is highly appreciated.

How can i click this button in a webpage?

```
<a class="buttonRed" href="what_would_you_do.html" onclick="this.blur();">
  <span>Get Started</span>
</a>
```

Comment: what actually you want to do ? redirect to a page or call the function on anchor click?

Comment: i want to automate few things. I have launched IE successfully. I have navigated to the url successfully. From the first page of the website i want to navigate to the second by clicking this button. I have no idea how to automate this (how to click this button )

Comment: actually this is not a button. its anchor tag. write your code as

Answer (score 2):

Short example which worked for me, tested with simple html file:

**ClickA.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><!-- Insert your title here --></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="buttonRed" href="what_would_you_do.html" onclick="this.blur();">
    <span>Get Started</span>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**vba standard module:**

```
' Add References:
' - Microsoft HTML Object Library
' - Microsoft Internet Controls

Sub test()
      Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
      Dim Document As htmlDocument
      Set Browser = New InternetExplorer

      Browser.Visible = True
      Browser.navigate "C:\Temp\VBA\ClickA.html"

      Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
          DoEvents
      Loop

      Set Document = Browser.Document
      Dim anchorElement As HTMLAnchorElement
      Set anchorElement = Document.getElementsByClassName("buttonRed").Item(Index:=1)
      anchorElement.Click
      Set Document = Nothing
      Set Browser = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

actually this is not a button. its anchor tag. write your code as

```
  <a class="buttonRed" href="what_would_you_do.html">
   <span>Get Started</span>
   </a>
```

and it will redirect to "what_would_you_do.html page (if its in root)